# Why size of int pointer is different of size of int array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Lets be the following code:

```
int x;
int *p = &x;
int t[3];
```

Then sizeof returns:

```
sizeof(x) -> 4
sizeof(p) -> 8
sizeof(t) -> 12
```

I suppose that `sizeof(t)` is the result of `3 * sizeof(int)`.
But as `t` is a pointer to his first element, its size should be `sizeof(p)`.

Why `sizeof(t)` returns the size of the memory block which represents the array ?

Thanks.

Comment: Because pointer is pointer and array is array. Why the size of a house is different than the size of piece of paper its address is written on?

Comment: "But as t is a pointer to his first element" this is false, `t` is an array, if you dereference it, you'll get the first element, that doesn't mean it has to be a pointer.

Comment: It is true that an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but an array in itself is not a pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the variable `t` is declared as having an array type

```
int t[3];
```

then `sizeof( t )` yields a value equal to `3 * sizeof( int )`

The C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand,

and indeed an array with three elements of type `int` occupies memory equal in bytes to `3 * sizeof( int )`.

In expressions with rare exceptions as using in the `sizeof` operator  array designators are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus if you will use for example the following expression

```
sizeof( t + 0 )
```

then `t` in the expression `t + 0` will be converted to pointer and you will get that `sizeof( t + 0 )` is equal to the size of a pointer to `int` on your platform, which is `8`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator** or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Answer (score 13):

`t` is an `int[3]` type, **not** a pointer type.

So its size is `3 * sizeof(int)`.

In certain instances, `t` *decays* to a pointer, but this is not one of those instances.